# CNN model not training on complete dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My dataset is the mnist sign_language_train image dataset with 27000 entries approx.
I partitioned it into a train set with 21000 entries approx and a validation set with 6000 entries approx. However when I am fitting the data into the model it only trains on 687 entries per epoch.

```
X_train, X_validate, y_train, y_validate = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size = 0.2,random_state = 123)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], *(28, 28, 1))
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], *(28, 28, 1))
X_validate = X_validate.reshape(X_validate.shape[0], *(28, 28, 1))

print(X_train.shape) -->(21964, 28, 28, 1)
print(y_train.shape) -->(21964,)
print(X_validate.shape) -->(5491, 28, 28, 1)
print(y_validate.shape) -->(5491,)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape = (28,28,1)))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64,activation ="relu"))
model.add(Dense(128,activation ="relu"))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128,activation ="relu"))
#model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Dense(25,activation ="softmax"))
```

And then I fit the above mentioned train and validation sets as shown below and for each epoch it trains on only 687 entries.

```
model.compile(optimizer=SGD(learning_rate=0.001), loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history2=model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 50, validation_data = (X_validate, y_validate))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused with the keras log. The number you see in Epoch log while training is not total number of samples but rather total number of batches. You have `21964` samples in train and the default batch size is 32, so you will see `21964/32=686.375=687` iterations ( last batch being not full). If you want to confirm, set the batch_size to 1 then you should see `21964` iterations, one sample per batch.

#### Sample

```
def train():
  mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
  print (x_train.shape)

  #nomalize data
  x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
  x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)
  #train model
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
  model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

  model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
          metrics=['accuracy'])
  model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
  return model

model = train()
```

output:

```
(60000, 28, 28)
1875/1875 [=====================] - 5s 2ms/step - loss: 0.2594 - accuracy: 0.9240
```

In the above example we have `60000` samples and batch size (defualt) of `32` so we should have `1875` iterations as shown in the epoch log.

Comment: Got it nice and clear . Thanks for the help !